# How to pass parameter to a ViewScoped Bean

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

Brief use-case description:

The user arrives to the page: `http://localhost:8080/.../show.xhtml?itemId=1`.
My `ShowBean` is a @RequestScoped JSF Managed Bean which obtains the id through `<f:viewParam.../>` and looks for item in the database:

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="itemId" value="#{showBean.itemId}">
        <f:convertNumber integerOnly="#{true}"/>
    </f:viewParam>
</f:metadata>
<f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{showBean.init()}"/>
```

The user can also edit the displayed item. I want to construct the @ViewScoped `ItemEditBean` on-demand (by clicking on the "Edit" button). To achieve this I did the following:

```
<p:commandButton value="Edit" oncomplete="editWidget.show()" update=":itemEditForm">
    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{itemEditBean.id}" value="#{showBean.itemId}"/>
</p:commandButton>
```

My questions are: Is there any better approach to pass itemId to the @ViewScoped bean?

**EDIT:**

Doing `itemEditBean.fetch(id)` in the action of the `p:command` button won't initialize the @ViewScoped bean on page rendering.

`<p:commandButton value="Edit" oncomplete="editWidget.show()" update=":itemEditForm" action="#{itemEditBean.fetchItem(showBean.itemId)}"/>`.

With the code above itemEditBean gets constructed on-demand.

Answer (score 0):

I think @ViewScoped is no pro.
Try partial form submit.
For example like this ,

```
 <p:commandLink immediate="true" id="addAccessoriesLink" update=":accessoriesEntryForm">  
        <h:graphicImage url="/images/add.png" styleClass="action-img"/>
              <f:setPropertyActionListener value="# AccessoriesActionBean.newAccessories}" target="#{AccessoriesActionBean.newAccessories}" />
  </p:commandLink>
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that `showEditBean` is re-constructed on `INVOKE_APPLICATION` in the subsequent request that does not preserve parameters.

just make sure to preserve them using `f:param`.

```
<p:commandButton value="Edit" oncomplete="editWidget.show()" update=":itemEditForm">
    <f:param name="itemId" value="#{showBean.itemId}"/>
    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{itemEditBean.id}" value="#{showBean.itemId}"/>
</p:commandButton>
```

P.S. you were right about `@ViewScoped` bean lifecycle: it is **NOT** constructed on page load  if appears only in `action`s!

Comment: yes, my dialog is dynamic="true" so your assumption is false. If you do any action which calls a method in your `@ViewScoped` bean returning an empty string for example, the `@ViewScoped` bean is destroyed.
So I can both construct it on demand and I can destroy it with an action in my p:dialog.

Comment: have you some binding="#{something}"?

how do you know that your bean has been destroyed? this is true only for <h:commandButton action="something"/> or <p:commandButton action="something" ajax="false"/>. if the view is the same the bean is not destroyed, unless for binding bug

Comment: No, I don't have any bindings. I'm returning itemId=1 from my `@ViewScoped` bean if the user clicks to any of the button in the dialog. So basically yes, I have <h:commandButton action="show.xhtml?itemId=1" ../>

Comment: finally I did something like `<p:commandButton value="Edit" oncomplete="editWidget.show()" update=":itemEditForm" action="#{itemEditBean.fetchItem(showBean.itemId)}"/>` which basically does what I wanted. The itemEditBean gets constructed on-demand, shownBean is populated and the id is passed.

Comment: having `#{itemEditBean}` in a **static** (outside a dynamic component) `ValueExpression` means that `itemEditBean` is constructed on page load, not on demand... consider using a debugger or print out a message inside constructor/@PostConstruct... indeed this works, but it is the same using only one `@ViewScoped` bean...

Comment: I can't confirm that. I registered a [lifecycle listener](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/09/debug-jsf-lifecycle.html) and put some println into the @PostConstruct. The only reference to the `itemEditBean` was inside the *action* call but the bean wasn't constructed on page load. Try it yourself.

Comment: i updated my answer. you were right about `@ViewScoped` bean lifecycle: it is **NOT** constructed on page load  if appears only in `action`s!